Counter example for Hadamard Differentiability
Hi and thank you for your help!
I am having a hard time fully understanding Hadamard differentiability.
I use the following definition taken from a german source (Brokate, Martin. 2014. "Konvexe Analysis und Evolutionsprobleme"):
$F: V \rightarrow W$ is Hadamard differentiable in $u\in V$ iff
$$\lim_{t\searrow 0} \frac{F(u+th+r(t))-F(u)}{t}$$ existis for all $h\in V$ and every $r:(0,\infty)\rightarrow V$ with $\lim_{t\searrow 0}\frac{r(t)}{t}=0$.
I want to proof the chain rule for the Hadamard derivative and highlight the contrast to non-Hadamard-differentiable functions, for which the chain rule does not hold in general. To do so I am looking for an example of a simple function, for which a directional derivative exists but not a Hadamard derivative. I couldn't find any, can someone of you help or maybe provide a good source?
Thank you so much!
